# C# projecting MongoDB fields from documents found by FilterDeffinition

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm having a huge problem with MongoDB, let's say i have a collection named Mails and in that collection there are documents in a structure like this:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("598da98cbfbc3c1e181604b7"),
"From" : "#############",
"To" : "#########",
"Uid" : "177",
"Message" : "#######",
"Subject" : "#######",
"New" : true,
"DateOfArrival" : "01.08.2017 15:11:12 +03:00",
"User" : ObjectId("560d0f40c1a5c309c44bf7ca"),
"TypeOfMail" : "inbox"
```

I removed sensitive data from the document, what i would like to do is get the documents Uid fields into anything that i can enumerate through, by the UserName field, i tried already this:

```
public async Task<List<string>> GetUidsByUserName(string userName)
    {
        FilterDefinition<TDocument> filter = Builders<TDocument>.Filter.Eq(u => u.User.UserName, userName);
        List<string> result = await Collection.Find(filter).Project(i => i.Uid).ToListAsync();
        return result;
    }
```

But this doesn't seem to work when i do tests on this it just doesn't pass through the Project line.

If anyone has any good ideas it would be very helpfull, and yes i tried already the solutions which i found on stackoverflow, none of them worked.

Comment: What do you mean the project line isn't passed through? In your example `i => i.Uid` is an expression and will be applied to the cursor returned by the `Find` method.

Comment: I mean that, when i run a test on this method and step through it with debugger the line with Project in it jumps out of the method back to the test and the test fails, without any exception or anything, the line:
`return result;` never gets executed.

Comment: There must be a underlining error being returned by the test? do you have same sample code?

Comment: Unable to determine the serialization information for u => u.User.UserName

Ohh, nvm found the problem instead of using `string userName` i should use the object User. Thx for pointing out.